# Access Activity within Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

Im making an App. And I want to access my 3 main activities into 3 different fragments. i use viewpager to swap activities but it only show layouts do not work on its functionality. Then i used Fragment to use functions. but my problem is same its only show layouts not is functions.
i made 3 different fragment for 3 activities and use

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings, container, false);
        return v;
}
```

method.
idont know how to use onActivityCreated() method or getActivity(). please help me..
i search all of it about it but cannot done yet.. :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow,I didn't get you? Please summarize your question more effective than this..

Comment: i want to acess my own avtivity into fragment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access Widget Of layout just use this
View.findViewById();